# Convert early-binding code to late-binding

Tags: vba, com, vb6, esri, late-binding

I've often written early-binding code in VBA and VB6 to automate office applications (Word, Excel, etc) then switched it to late-binding to handle multiple versions of those applications.  I'm trying to do the same thing but I am automating an ESRI ArcMap GIS application and the concepts I've used in the past do not seem to be translating.

---

The following code runs correctly:

```
Sub EarlyBinding()
Dim ArcMap As esriArcMapUI.MxDocument

    Set ArcMap = GetObject("C:\Users\Mike\Downloads\Assessment Mapping.mxd", _
                           "esriArcMapUI.MxDocument")
    Debug.Print ArcMap.Title
End Sub
```

---

But this code fails with *Object doesn't support this property or method* on the `Debug.Print` line:

```
Sub LateBinding()
Dim ArcMap As Object

    Set ArcMap = GetObject("C:\Users\Mike\Downloads\Assessment Mapping.mxd", _
                           "esriArcMapUI.MxDocument")
    Debug.Print ArcMap.Title

End Sub
```

Is there something special about MS Office apps that they support this approach better than COM servers in general?  Or something special about ESRI apps that they *do not* support this approach?

Comment: Retagged w/o VB6.  There is no VB6 question here.

Comment: I tagged this VB6 because of the overlap with VBA.  I assumed the concepts discussed here apply equally to both VBA and VB6.  Please correct me if I'm wrong in my assumption.

Comment: You're right, VBA and VB6 are virtually the same thing, only VBA doesn't have a compiler to compile to native code, just the psuedocode engine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's most likely that the Esri object isn't supporting IDISPATCH properly. You might try CALLBYNAME, but I'm guessing that won't work either because I believe it vectors through IDispatch as well.

Comment: So the first example (using early-binding) could still work if the ESRI object does not support IDISPATCH?

Comment: Yes, early binding doesn't go through IDispatch so those calls should still work properly. That'd be kind of a weird situation, but it's certainly possible. You can also have the opposite, an object that ONLY supports IDISPATCH and doesn't expose any other interfaces at all. Objects intended only for scripting use will sometimes behave that way, though I can't think of one right off anymore...