# Convert early binding code to late binding

Tags: vba, excel, late-binding, early-binding

I have difficulty converting early binding code to late binding. I have tried several times but it doesn't work properly. When it comes to early binding it works well. 
Here is my code and I'd like to ask you to show me how it should look like and in which places I have to make changes and for what.

```
Sub PrezentacjaPP()

    Dim PowerPointA As PowerPoint.Application 'aplikacja PowerPoint
    Dim PrezentacjaPP As PowerPoint.Presentation 'prezentacja PowerPoint
    Dim NazwaPP As String 'nazwa pliku z szablonem prezentacji
    Dim SlajdPP As PowerPoint.Slide 'slajd prezentacji PowerPoint
    Dim WykresPP As PowerPoint.Shape 'wykres w formacie obrazu
    Dim Lista As String 'lista marek
    Dim Tekst As String 'tekst z info o marce i statystykami
    Dim i As Long 'numer marki
    Dim Wiersz As Long 'numer pierwszego wiersza dla danej marki

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'Wyłącz odświeżanie ekranu


        '1.Usunięcie starych prezentacji
        NazwaPP = Dir(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "Prezentacja_*.pptx")
        If NazwaPP <> "" Then
            If MsgBox("Czy usunąć istniejące pliki z prezentacjami PowerPoint?", _
                vbYesNo + vbInformation) = vbYes Then
                Do While NazwaPP <> ""
                    Kill ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & NazwaPP
                    NazwaPP = Dir()
                Loop
            Else
                MsgBox "Zmień nazwę istniejących prezentacji i ponownie uruchom procedurę."
                CzyZakonczyc = True
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If

        '2. Wczytanie zmiennych
        ChDrive Left(ThisWorkbook.Path, 1) 'domyślny dysk
        ChDir ThisWorkbook.Path 'domyślny katalog
        NazwaPP = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Prezentacje programu PowerPoint (*.pptx), *.pptx", Title:="Zaznacz plik z szablonem prezentacji PowerPoint")
        If NazwaPP = "False" Then
            CzyZakonczyc = True
            Exit Sub
        End If

        '3. Wczytanie i otwarcie szablonu prezentacji PowerPoint
        Set PowerPointA = New PowerPoint.Application
        Set PrezentacjaPP = PowerPointA.Presentations.Open(NazwaPP) '<-- tylko w celach poglądowych podczas testowania makra

        '4. Stworzenie prezentacji
        With PrezentacjaPP

            '4.1. Uzupełnienie slajdów wstępnych
            .Slides(1).Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange = Cells(NrWiersza, "B").Value 'Slajd nr 1
            .Slides(2).Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange = "Lista marek" 'Slajd nr 2
            For i = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, 18).End(xlUp).Row - 1
               Lista = Lista & Cells(i + 1, "R") & vbNewLine
            Next i
            .Slides(2).Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange = Lista

                '4.1.1. Stworzenie slajdów z aktywami
                 For i = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, 18).End(xlUp).Row - 1
                     'Dodanie nowego slajdu (typ ppLayoutText: tytuł oraz pole tekstowe)
                     Set SlajdPP = .Slides.Add(.Slides.Count + 1, ppLayoutText)
                     With SlajdPP
                     'Wstawienie tytułu slajdu
                     .Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange = Cells(i + 1, "R")

            '4.2. Dodanie wykresów

                '4.2.1. Wykres 1
                ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Picture" & " " & i * 2 - 1)).Select 'wykres w formacie obrazu w Excel'u
                Selection.Copy
                .Shapes.Paste
                Set WykresPP = .Shapes(SlajdPP.Shapes.Count)

                '4.2.2. Pozycjonowanie wykresu na slajdzie
                With WykresPP
                    .Left = 40
                    .Top = 110
                    .LockAspectRatio = msoFalse 'odblokowanie wsp. proporcji
                    .Width = 400
                    .Height = 195
                End With

                '4.2.3. Wykres 2
                ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Picture" & " " & i * 2)).Select 'wykres w formacie obrazu w Excel'u
                Selection.Copy
                .Shapes.Paste
                Set WykresPP = .Shapes(SlajdPP.Shapes.Count)

                '4.2.4. Pozycjonowanie wykresu na slajdzie
                With WykresPP
                    .Left = 40
                    .Top = 315
                    .LockAspectRatio = msoFalse 'odblokowanie wsp. proporcji
                    .Width = 400
                    .Height = 195
                End With

            '4.3. Doddanie statystyk

                '4.3.1. Wyznaczenie numeru pierwszego wiersza dla danej marki
                Wiersz = NrWiersza + 3 + 25 * (i - 1)

                '4.3.2 Wczytanie statystyk
                Tekst = Cells(Wiersz, 2) & " " & Cells(Wiersz, 3) & vbNewLine & _
                    Cells(Wiersz + 20, 2) & " " & FormatNumber(Cells(Wiersz + 20, 4), 2) & vbNewLine & _
                    Cells(iersz + 21, 2) & " " & Cells(iersz + 21, 4) & vbNewLine & _
                    Cells(Wiersz + 22, 2) & " " & Cells(Wiersz + 22, 4) & vbNewLine & _
                    Cells(Wiersz + 22, 2) & " " & Cells(Wiersz + 22, 4) & vbNewLine & _
                    vbNewLine & _
                    Cells(Wiersz + 20, 6) & " " & FormatNumber(Cells(Wiersz + 20, 9), 2) & vbNewLine & _
                    Cells(Wiersz + 21, 6) & " " & Cells(Wiersz + 21, 9) & vbNewLine & _
                    Cells(Wiersz + 22, 6) & " " & Cells(Wiersz + 22, 9) & vbNewLine & _
                    vbNewLine & _
                    Cells(Wiersz + 20, 11) & " " & Cells(Wiersz + 20, 13) & vbNewLine & _
                    Cells(Wiersz + 21, 11) & " " & Cells(Wiersz + 21, 13)

                '4.3.3. Pozycjonowanie pola
                .Shapes(2).Top = 110
                .Shapes(2).Left = 500
                .Shapes(2).Width = 330
                .Shapes(2).Height = 410
                .Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange = Tekst

        End With
        Next i

        '4.4. Stworzenie slajdu końcowego

            '4.4.1. Dodanie slajdu
            Set SlajdPP = PowerPointA.Presentations(1).Slides.Add _
                (PowerPointA.Presentations(1).Slides.Count + 1, ppLayoutText)
            SlajdPP.Shapes(1).Delete

            '4.4.2. Uzupełnienie slajdu
            With SlajdPP.Shapes(1)
                .TextFrame.TextRange = "DZIĘKUJĘ ZA UWAGĘ"
                .TextFrame.HorizontalAnchor = msoAnchorCenter
                .TextFrame.VerticalAnchor = msoAnchorMiddle
                .TextEffect.FontBold = msoCTrue
                .TextEffect.FontSize = 24
                .TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 100, 170)
            End With

        End With

        '5. Zapisanie prezentacji PowerPoint
        PrezentacjaPP.SaveAs Excel.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Prezentacja_PP_" & Date & ".pptx"

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True 'Włącz odświeżanie ekranu

End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert early-binding code to late-binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5341544/convert-early-binding-code-to-late-binding)

Answer (score 4):

Late-binding means VBA only has run-time knowledge of the types involved. This is late-bound:

```
Dim PowerPointA As Object
```

That declaration will compile with or without the `PowerPoint` type library referenced.

Because VBA doesn't (can't) know what members `PowerPointA` has, you don't get *IntelliSense* at design-time, and this will happily compile...

```
PowerPointA.SomeMemberThatDoesNotExist
```

...and blow up at run-time with error 438 "Object doesn't support this property or method".

Any member call made against `Object` or `Variant` is late-bound; at run-time, VBA needs to query the interface to locate the member and determine its existence: this means late-bound code incurs a slight overhead that early-bound code doesn't need to.

---

Early-binding means VBA has compile-time knowledge of the types involved. This is early-bound:

```
Dim PowerPointA As PowerPoint.Application
```

That declaration can only ever compile when the `PowerPoint` type library is referenced.

Because VBA knows what members `PowerPointA` has, you get *IntelliSense* (and autocompletion) at design-time, and this <s>will</s> *should* not compile:

```
PowerPointA.SomeMemberThatDoesNotExist
```

...however `Application` is likely an *extensible* COM interface (`Excel.Application` is); if that's the case then VBA will compile the code, and `SomeMemberThatDoesNotExist` will be a late-bound member call that will blow up at run-time with error 438 "Object doesn't support this property or method".

---

When you want to "convert early-bound code to late-bound code", what you really mean is that you want to *remove a type library reference from your project and still be able to compile and run the code*.

Assuming that reference is the `PowerPoint` type library, this means you need to replace everything in your code that is defined in this library - because once you remove the reference, classes such as `PowerPoint.Application`, `PowerPoint.Presentation`, `PowerPoint.Slide` and `PowerPoint.Shape` won't be defined anymore, and stop meaning anything to VBA. Therefore:

1. Replace declarations `As [PowerPoint.][ClassName]` with `As Object`
2. Replace `New [PowerPoint.][ClassName]` with `CreateObject("ProgIdForThatClass")`
3. Remove the reference to the `PowerPoint` type library
4. Compile the project. Doesn't compile? Back to 1.

The `ProgId` for `PowerPoint.Application` happens to be `"PowerPoint.Application"`, so you can replace this:

```
Set PowerPointA = New PowerPoint.Application
```

With this:

```
Set PowerPointA = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
```

And that's all you need to do.

If you have code elsewhere that references constants defined in the `PowerPoint` type library, you'll want to either replace them with their underlying value, or define equivalent constants yourself, so instead of this:

```
foo = ppEffectFade
```

You'll have this:

```
foo = 1793 'PowerPoint.PpEntryEffect.ppEffectFade=1793
```

Or this:

```
Const ppEffectFade As Long = 1793
```

```
foo = ppEffectFade
```

Or this:

```
Public Enum PpEntryEffect
    ppEffectAppear = 3844
    ppEffetFade = 1793
    '...
End Enum
```

```
foo = ppEffectFade
```

You can locate all constants, their values, and everything defined in any referenced type library, using the *Object Browser* (<kbd>F2</kbd>):

[image: object browser showing definition of PowerPoint.PpEntryEffect.ppEffectAppear]

Comment: Many thanks, I did what you wrote. So now it looks like this:Dim PowerPointA As Object 'aplikacja PowerPoint
Dim PrezentacjaPP As Object 'prezentacja PowerPoint
Dim NazwaPP As String 'nazwa pliku z szablonem prezentacji
Dim SlajdPP As Object 'slajd prezentacji PowerPoint
Dim WykresPP As Object 'wykres w formacie obrazu
Dim Lista As String 'lista marek
Dim Tekst As String 'tekst z info o marce i statystykami
Dim i As Long 'numer marki
Dim Wiersz As Long 'numer pierwszego wiersza dla danej marki

Comment: Many thanks, I did what you wrote but I received a massage: Slides.Add: Invalid enumeration value. Do I have to change this line of code: Set PrezentacjaPP = PowerPointA.Presentations.Open(NazwaPP)

Comment: @Arkadiusz Assuming your early-bound code works in the first place, you shouldn't have anything to change, other than the declaration types.

Comment: @Arkadiusz the invalid enum value is `ppLayoutText`, see the bottom part of this answer, starting at "If you have code elsewhere that **references constants defined in the PowerPoint type library**".

Comment: No problem. Feel free to mark the question as answered by checking the hollow checkmark next to the voting buttons near the top of this answer. Cheers!